# How to not display a table when it's empty?

Tags: angular

I have a table that is getting populated using an array of objects in angular 2. Now when the array of objects is empty, the table has no rows except for the table header cells. How can I display a message that the table is empty and not show the table header row?

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover fixed-header" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Event Name</th>
            <th>Circle</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>                         
            <th>Start Time</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
            <th>End Time</th>
            <th>Randomize</th>
            <th>Priority</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let event of eventList">
            <td>{{ event.id.eventId }}</td>
            <td>{{ event.eventName }}</td>
            <td>{{ event.circles }}</td>
            <td>{{ event.startDate | date : "dd-MM-y" }}</td>
            <td>{{ event.startTime }}</td>
            <td>{{ event.endDate | date : "dd-MM-y"  }}</td>
            <td>{{ event.endTime }}</td>
            <td>{{ event.randomize }}</td>
            <td>{{ event.priority }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>                
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ngIf to check the length of the array and if the count is zero display the message.

```
   <div *ngIf="eventList.length == 0"> 
        <h1> No events </h1>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="eventList.length > 0">
     <table class="table table-bordered table-hover fixed-header" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Event Name</th>
                <th>Circle</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>                         
                <th>Start Time</th>
                <th>End Date</th>
                <th>End Time</th>
                <th>Randomize</th>
                <th>Priority</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let event of eventList">
                <td>{{ event.id.eventId }}</td>
                <td>{{ event.eventName }}</td>
                <td>{{ event.circles }}</td>
                <td>{{ event.startDate | date : "dd-MM-y" }}</td>
                <td>{{ event.startTime }}</td>
                <td>{{ event.endDate | date : "dd-MM-y"  }}</td>
                <td>{{ event.endTime }}</td>
                <td>{{ event.randomize }}</td>
                <td>{{ event.priority }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>                
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: i deleted my answer for this to avoid confusion. I think this should solve your question